# Concurrency (thread executor) for OUTPUT channels for Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-cloud-stream

Is there a way to configure the concurrency for the output channels in spring cloud streams ?

For instance, I am thinking a way of how we could set up the thread executor, for the Output MessageChannel or via configuration properties, if that is a good idea at all, in case of spring cloud stream services.

I haven't found a way to do, so is that means that spring stream cloud manage the concurrency (the number of threads, scale up/down policy) for us in a nicely way and it's better we to not touch that part ?

Many thanks in advance,
Simeon

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Both rabbitmq and kafka (the main binders) publishing is asynchronous (aka very fast).

Comment: The idea is to find how the concurrency works (threads policy etc ... ) and if we to have the power to manage that concurrency, if we want to. Is there a source from where I can see how the concurrency works for the output channels and how could be configured, if we want to? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concurrency built into the producer side, since it's not needed because, with the standard binders, sends are async and, in any case, the concurrency is managed on the input side.

If you want to experiment, use a task executor within your application; if you find a compelling case for adding it to the framework, open a github issue asking for a new feature.

Comment: We have actually changed the configuration from async to sync, because for our specific use case, we had a REST controller that consumed a POST request and sent the payload to Kafka. For this reason, we wanted to return a 404/500 response in the scenario when Kafka was unavailable. This was achieved by changing the configuration of the appropriate binder to 'sync'. My understanding is that this should not be an issue with regards to concurrency, as message execution will be done in the corresponding HTTP thread associated to the request. Is this a valid hypothesis?

Comment: Yes; and that is true in general - even for a `Processor`, the concurrency is controlled by the consumer side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, and just to be absolutely clear, as we are using a Spring Boot application with the default 200 HTTP threads - from your response we understand that every thread will be individually talking to the output message channel without blocking any other thread in the application - correct?

Comment: That is correct, yes; the concurrency is controlled/configured by the web container (Tomcat etc).

Comment: Thank you very much, as always appreciate your help and prompt response